# Drawing line with SpriteKit and detecting collision

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I have managed to draw a line with array of my random CGPoints.

```
    -(void)drawLine
    {
    SKShapeNode *mainLine = [SKShapeNode node];
    CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, 0, 0);

    for(int i;i<pointsInMyView.count;i++)
    {
        CGPoint myPoint = [pointsInMyView[i] CGPointValue];
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, myPoint.x, myPoint.y);
        mainLine.path = pathToDraw;
    }
    [mainLine setLineWidth:40];
    [mainLine setStrokeColor:[SKColor whiteColor]];
    mainLine.name = @"mainLine";
    [self addChild:mainLine];


}
```

As you can see I am drawing a SKShapeNode. My goal is to check collision of my SKSpriteNode with my line. But of course, this shape node makes a frame that contains all points of my line, and in this case my ShapeNode is all over my view. My SpriteNode detects collision with this ShapeNode all the time.
I should draw multiple different ShapeNodes I guess, so every node would have its own frame. But if i do it this way, my line is not connected.
Is there some solution to draw this node by node and still get nice line.

Comment: If your SKShapeNode is made up of random points, then it will spread all over the screen (I've just tried it).

I think you will have to devise some algorithm to ensure that the line does not cross over itself, and forms a relatively simple line.

Can you post your code that generates `[pointsInMyView]`?

Comment: I know that my shape node is all ower my screen. The point is that I need those random points. My line is just a big shape node with vector lines from one point to another. This is ok. But now I am working on how to detect collision with my touch location and line that i drawn. Problem is that collision is detected all the time when I'm inside node frame. I want my touch wont respond on empty pixels of my shape node, just on pixels where my line is drawn. Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to detect a touch on the line or another sprite contacting the lines?

Comment: I am trying to detect touch on my line that i drawn as a ShapeNode, so I need to ignore empty pixels of my ShapeNode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately nodes in SpriteKit cannot be concave (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConcavePolygon.html), with lines that cross over each other.

You will have to create separate nodes for each lines between adjacent points and then possibly join them together. you could do this either by:

1. Create the 1st segment and then add subsequent segments as children
   of that 1st segment.
2. Create a non-visible node for the whole line and add wll the line
   segments as children of that node.
3. Create physicsbodies for each segment and join them with
       `SKPhysicsJointFixed`.

Comment: I suddenly remembered this after playing around with this in a test project and getting weird behavior, so deleted my previous answer.

Comment: These are sure options to solve my problem..I have also read some posts about getting a texture from ShapeNode and then presenting a new SpriteNode, with physics and then detecting collision. This is definitely  good option, but my texture that I am creating like: SKTexture *texture = [self.view textureFromNode:mainLine]; is always NUL, and my new SpriteNode is than empty if I add it to the scene. Have to figure out what is wrong here.. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You mention collisions, but then you say you only want to detect touches on the line (the border of the node). But you'll have the same problems if your shape is defined by a random set of points unless you can guarantee that the shape they make is concave.

Comment: Yes i messed up a bit. First I was trying to detect collision with my touch and after that, collision between two spritenodes. I understand now your point! But have problems now how with creation my line on your recommendations.